# python tablefmt="simple_grid" not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, tabulate, python-tabulate

I try to make simple_grid table but it is not working instead it showing simple table

```
from tabulate import tabulate

table = [["praveen", "cse", "molasi"],`["vasanth", "cse", "thokavadi"],["yogesh", "cse", "ksr"]]
headers = ["Name", "Dept", "Home"]

output = tabulate(table, headers, tablefmt="simple_grid")

print(output)
```

```
Name     Dept    Home
-------  ------  ---------
praveen  cse     molasi
vasanth  cse     thokavadi
yogesh   cse     ksr
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of what you are looking for?